# unity2d instantiate prefab animator working partly

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript

okay so my enemies are being instantiated in my main.js 
but the animator is attached to this prefab of enemy ( it is a sprite animation )
it works on certian enemies 
for instance 
0will work
1 wont work
1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0 and so on it seems random 
also my enemies spawn between 6 and 9 seconds.

i just cant figure this out 
one problem after another.:( (guess this sums up a beginers game dev).
nearly done though.

thanks for your help stackoverflow community.

```
#pragma strict
var enemy : GameObject;
var speed : float = 1.0;
var enemanim : Animator;
var isdying : boolean = false;

function Start () {
this.transform.position.x = 8.325;
this.transform.position.y = -1.3;
enemanim = GetComponent(Animator);
enemanim.SetFloat("isdead",0);
}

function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) {
if(coll.gameObject.CompareTag("distroy")){
Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
}
if(coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && main.jumped == true){

 isdying=true;
 }
}

function Update () {
this.transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
this.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(-5,0);
if (isdying==true){
enemanim.SetFloat("isdead",1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
enemanim.Play();
```

It is working on and off because some of your Enemies are set to play automatically through the Editor.

Comment: nope dont work i have set the value of the float and some enemise do destroy

Comment: Yeah, I see what it is. Your logic is a bit convoluted, no offense. What is the "distroy" tag some world boundary?

Comment: the distroy is a tag i linked to an object off screen to allow the enemies to destroy them selfs